# Attach file with Capybara - Element is not currently visible and > so may not be interacted with

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to attach file using Capybara.
Input element is:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="uploadfile[]" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px 0px 0px -175px; padding: 0px; width: 220px; height: 30px; font-size: 14px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer; display: block; z-index: 2147483583; top: 3331px; left: 436px;">
```

Code for attaching file is:

```
attach_file 'uploadfile[]', '/home/user/image.jpg'
```

But it returns error:

```
biske@biske:~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/AddPlace$ ruby
test.rb  [remote server]
file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130223-30353-dw596v/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7537:in
`fxdriver.preconditions.visible': Element is not currently visible and
so may not be interacted with
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)  from [remote
server]
file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130223-30353-dw596v/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10207:in
`DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_'  from [remote server]
file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130223-30353-dw596v/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10226:in
`DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'   from [remote server]
file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130223-30353-dw596v/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10231:in
`DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'   from [remote server]
file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20130223-30353-dw596v/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10171:in
`DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'  from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in
`assert_ok'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in
`initialize'  from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in
`new'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in
`create_response'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in
`request'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in
`call'  from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:615:in
`raw_execute'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:593:in
`execute'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:400:in
`sendKeysToElement'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:126:in
`send_keys'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb:33:in
`set'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:79:in
`block in set'  from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:78:in
`synchronize'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:79:in
`set'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:144:in
`attach_file'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:341:in
`block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'   from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in
`block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'  from test.rb:19:in `add_place'
  from test.rb:11:in `run'  from test.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Ivan, I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. Probably the page has not fully loaded and you are trying to grab the element a tad too early. Ideally you should introduce a delay before trying to attach..

Answer (score 8):

```
attach_file('locator', 'path/to/file.jpg', :visible => false )
```

Should do the trick. Capybara ignores hidden fields by default, all you need to do is pass in a visibility option

Answer (score 1):

The `:visible` option did nothing for me. There seems to be a `:make_visible` option:

```
attach_file 'uploadfile[]', '/home/user/image.jpg', :make_visible => true
```

or instead of `true` with a Hash of custom style properties which will be set to overwrite before attempting to open the file dialog.

Answer (score -5):

Because Ruby is not very good with page loading, if I were you, I'll solve it like this:

```
!30.times { if (driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@type='file']")rescue false) then break else sleep 1; end }
```

Basically the code above will try 30 times (every 1 sec) to search for the element that you are trying to attach and will exit the loop if the element is present. You can use variables after the break or after the sleep command to direct your flow if you want.

Best of luck